# A proof for the interior product

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

How should I approach a proof like the following for the interior product:

> Let $K$ be a field and $V$ a $K$-vector space. And $\omega_i \in V^*$ with $V^*$ the dual space to $V$. It is given that $$\iota_v(\omega_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega_p) = \omega_1(v)\omega_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega_p.$$
> Now it is to be proven that:
> $$\iota_v(\omega_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_p)=\sum_{i=1}^p (-1)^{i-1}(\iota_v\omega_i) \omega_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{\omega_i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_p. \tag{1}$$

I tried using the definition of the wedge product through the sum over the permutations of $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$ and the tensor product of the given dual vectors and used the iota function on this definition, because it is given how the tensor product behaves under it. So
$$\iota_v(\omega_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_p) = \iota_v \bigg(\sum_{\sigma\in S_p} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \omega_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega_{\sigma(p)} \bigg).$$

But wasn't sure whether or not I was allowed then to change the sum over the permutations to a sum over $1$ to $p$.

Comment: So what have you done? Where are you stuck? Don't just give us your exercises with no effort.

Comment: Hint: [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)

Comment: OK, this is a better start :) $S_k$ should of course be $S_p$. You're missing a numerical factor and some signs in the definition of the wedge product. How many elements are there in $S_p$? A lot more than $p$ of them. How many terms are there where $\omega_i$ appears at the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you've made some serious progress. Now here's a hint to proceed to the next step. Consider dividing $S_p$ up into subsets $S_p(i) = \{\sigma: \sigma(1)=i\}$. You should convince yourself that these are all (right) cosets of $S_{p-1}$. This breaks your sum up into $\sum_{i=1}^p$. Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes, your tipp helped a lot. I could finish the proof now.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer when you're satisfied.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060812/calculate-the-interior-product-of-an-elementary-form), please? I do not really underastand your answer: could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You'll have to ask something more specific (and no, I'm not going to read your 5-page question). We're partitioning $S_p$ into the right cosets of $S_{p-1}$ and then using the fact that $\text{sgn}(\sigma\circ\tau) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)\text{sgn}(\tau)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So, if I well understood $S_p$ is the set of the permutation of $p$ elements and so you say that it is the disjoint union of the set $S^{1,i}_p,....,S^{p,i}_p$ where $S^{j,i}$ is for each $j=1,...,p$ the set of the elements of $S_p$ that interchange the $j$-th element with $i$-th element, right?

Comment: So we have now $$
i_{\vec v}(\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k):=i_\vec v\big(k!\text{Alt}(\vec v^1\otimes...\otimes\vec v^k)\big))=\\
i_{\vec v}\Biggl(\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot T^\sigma(\vec v^1\otimes...\otimes\vec v^k)\Biggl)=
i_{\vec v}\Biggl(\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot\vec v^{\sigma_1}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_k})\Biggl)=\\
$$

Comment: $$
\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot\ i_{\vec v}(\vec v^{\sigma_1}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_k})=...=\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}\Biggl(\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)v^{\sigma_r}(\vec v)\cdot\vec v^{\sigma_1}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_{r-1}}\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_{r+1}}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_k}\Biggl)
$$ and thus fixing $r$ if we broke $S_k$ into the disjoint union of $S_k^{i,r}$ then

Comment: $$\sum_{\sigma\in S_k^{i,k}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)v^{\sigma_r}(\vec v)\cdot\vec v^{\sigma_1}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_{r-1}}\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_{r+1}}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{\sigma_k}\neq 0$$ if and only if $i=r$ and so the statement follows. Is this what your answer says?

Comment: But why the last summation is not zero if and only if $i=r$? Could you explain this to me, pelase?

Comment: Anyway I edit the question: now it is on of one or two pages and I prove to solve the problem using Laplace formula but unfortunately I did not prove the idetity only for one factor as you can see.

Comment: @Antonio No. I care *only* about the first position, not about the rest — because I am trying to contract with $v$ in the first position precisely. So do not guess that I meant to make the problem far more complicated. I defined *only* $S_p(i)$ and said to observe/prove that as $i$ varies we get the $p$ different cosets of the subgroup $S_{p-1}$. That is all we need.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, but regarding more carrefuly the question it seems that the above definition of interior product is different from [mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060812/prove-that-big%ce%b9-vec-vt-big-vec-v-1-vec-v-k-1-sum-r-1k-1?noredirect=1#comment8391246_4060812): so probably it is right that my result it the same of that above but multiplied for the factor $k$, right?