# Prove that $\big[ι_{\vec v}(T)\big](\vec v_1,...,\vec v_{k-1}):=\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}T(\vec v_1,...,\vec v_{r-1},\vec v,\vec v_r,...,\vec v_{k-1})$

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

**Definition**

Let $V$ be a vector space and $k$ a non-negative integer. Given $T\in\mathcal L^k(V)$ and $\vec v\in V$ let $i_{\vec v}T$ be the $(k-1)$-tensor which takes the value
$$
\big[\iota_{\vec v}(T)\big](\vec v_1,...,\vec v_{k-1}):=\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}T(\vec v_1,...,\vec v_{r-1},\vec v,\vec v_r,...,\vec v_{k-1})
$$
for any $\vec v_1,..,\vec v_{k-1}\in V$.

So it is not hard to show that the operation above defined is linear with respect $\vec v$ and $T$ and moreover it is not hard to show that
$$
\iota_{\vec v}\big(\vec v^1\otimes...\otimes\vec v^k\big)=\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}v^r(\vec v)\cdot\vec v^1\otimes...\otimes\vec v^{r-1}\otimes\vec v^{r+1}\otimes...\otimes\vec v^k 
$$
for any $\vec v^1,...,\vec v^k\in V^*$ and thus using this I tried to prove that
$$
\iota_{\vec v}(\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k)=\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}v^r(\vec v)\cdot\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^{r-1}\wedge\vec v^{r+1}\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k 
$$
but unfortenately I did not be able to do it. So could someone helpme, please?

To follow a my proof attempt.

**MY PROOF ATTEMPT**

To follow I use Laplace formula with respect the $r$-th column

$$
\big[\iota_{\vec v}(\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k)\big](\vec w_1,...,\vec w_{k-1}):=\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}\big[\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k\big](\vec w_1,...,\vec w_{r-1},\vec v,\vec w_r,...,\vec w_{k-1})=\\
\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}\det\begin{pmatrix}v^1(\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&v^1(\vec w_{r-1})&&v^1(\vec v)&&v^1(\vec w_r)&&\cdots&&v^1(\vec w_{k-1})\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
v^k(\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&v^k(\vec w_{r-1})&&v^k(\vec v)&&v^k(\vec w_r)&&\cdots&&v^k(\vec w_{k-1})\end{pmatrix}=\\
\sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}\sum_{h=1}^k(-1)^{h+r}v^h(\vec v)\det\begin{pmatrix}v^1(\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&v^1(\vec w_{r-1})&&v^1(\vec w_r)&&\cdots&&v^1(\vec w_{k-1})\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
v^{h-1}(\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&v^{h-1}(\vec w_{r-1})&&v^{h-1}(\vec w_r)&&\cdots&&v^{h-1}(\vec w_{k-1})\\
v^{h+1}(\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&v^{h+1}(\vec w_{r-1})&&v^{h+1}(\vec w_r)&&\cdots&&v^{h+1}(\vec w_{k-1})\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
v^k(\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&v^k(\vec w_{r-1})&&v^k(\vec w_r)&&\cdots&&v^k(\vec w_{k-1})\end{pmatrix}=\\
\sum_{r=1}^k\sum_{h=1}^k(-1)^{r-1}(-1)^{h+r}v^h(\vec v)\big[\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^{h-1}\wedge\vec v^{h+1}\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k\big](\vec w_1,...,\vec w_{k-1})=\\
\sum_{r=1}^k\sum_{h=1}^k(-1)^{h-1}v^h(\vec v)\big[\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^{h-1}\wedge\vec v^{h+1}\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k\big](\vec w_1,...,\vec w_{k-1})=\\
k\cdot\sum_{h=1}^k(-1)^{h-1}v^h(\vec v)\big[\vec v^1\wedge...\wedge\vec v^{h-1}\wedge\vec v^{h+1}\wedge...\wedge\vec v^k\big](\vec w_1,...,\vec w_{k-1})
$$

So as you can see the formula is different only of the factor $k$ but unfortunately I do not see where is my mistake: so could you help me, please?

Comment: I don't see any mistake in the proof and an example shows that we indeed need the extra factor of $k$ in the formula above. Note that $\iota_\nu$ sometimes is defined in a different way, namely by: $$(\iota_\nu T)(v_1,\dots,v_{k-1})=T(v,v_1,\dots,v_{k-1})$$ i.e. only the first term of the sum in your definition. In that case we don't need the factor $k$.

Comment: @leoli1 Okay, so [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998468/a-proof-for-the-interior-product?noredirect=1&lq=1) result is wrong?

Comment: No, there they use the definition of $\iota_\nu$ I mentioned.

Comment: If you were to make the convention that for an anti-symmetric $T$ you have (with some abuse of notation) $T(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)=T(v_1∧v_2∧...∧v_k)$, then the alternating insertion sum needs a factor $\frac1k$ to be compatible with the more general insertion as per leoli.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, but the identity $$T(\vec v_1,\vec v_2,...,\vec v_k)=T(\vec v_1\wedge\vec v_2\wedge...\wedge\vec v_k)$$ confuses me: I do not really understand how $T$ could be a tensor; so what is $T$ precisely? Could you explain better, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: @leoli1 Oh yeah! So the definition of interior product given in the question I liked is different from mine, right? Excuse me but I did not realise: I read a bit quickly the question.

Comment: $T$ on the left is a multilinear functional, which in general gets identified with a tensor. $T$ on the right is a linear function on a tensor space, so can also be identified as a tensor. If $T$ is *anti-symmetric*, and the wedge product defined as you used, then contrary to what I assumed as intuitive one would get $T(v_1∧v_2∧...∧v_k)=k!T(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)$. But one can shorten your proof even more, for any anti-symmetric $T$ you get that $T(v_1,..,v_{r-1},v,v_{r},...,v_{k-1})=(-1)^{r-1}T(v,v_1,...,v_{k-1})$. Then you get directly to your result, without determinants.